# What is Oracle equivalent of OBJECT_ID?

Tags: oracle

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OMEGA."IPO_GET"
(cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)IS
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR
      SELECT i.* , 
             CASE 
             WHEN OBJECT_ID(
                    DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(i.ipo_code||'_exchange_data'),
                    'U'
                  ) IS NOT NULL
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END CASE
      FROM   IPO_MASTER i
      order by start_date DESC;
END;
```

I am getting the error:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "OBJECT_ID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: In this case it is telling you that `OBJECT_ID` is not a valid column name for the `IPO_MASTER` table. Are you trying to do some kind of dynamic column name resolution?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the OBJECT_ID? I'm not familiar what is should do? What database do you know where this SQL works?

Answer (score 0):

I might be far from what you actually expect, but in Oracle there is a table `all_objects`, where all the objects are stored and this query:

```
SELECT object_id
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE owner       = <your SCHEMA>
   AND object_name = <your OBJECT>
```

will return unique id of the given object if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't have a function ORACLE_ID like [the one in SQL Server](https://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/03/what-is-object_id-in-sql-server/). But you could use the data dictionary to solve your problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OMEGA."IPO_GET"
(cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)IS
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR
      SELECT i.* , 
             nvl2(ut.table_name, 1, 0) as haz_exch_data_table
      FROM   IPO_MASTER i
      left outer join user_tables ut
        on ut.table_name = i.ipo_code||'_EXCHANGE_DATA'
      order by start_date DESC;
END;
```

If there is an exchange data table prefixed by a value of `i.ipo_code` then  `haz_exch_data_table` will be `1` else it will be `0`.